# Select statement inside SSRS textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to assign values to textboxes in SSRS but am running into a bit of trouble.

My dataset "dsStepInfo" groups and sums a number of rows together based on "ID", query below.

```
SELECT       ID, SUM(Target) AS Target, SUM(Actual) AS Actual
FROM         tblStepComplete
WHERE        (CompleteID = @ParamID)
GROUP BY     ID
```

And returns:

```
   ID      Target     Actual
-------------------------------
|  10   |  44418   |  44418   |
-------------------------------
|  12   |  13193   |  13123   |
-------------------------------
|  22   |  1411    |  1411    |
-------------------------------
|  50   |  160     |  80      |
-------------------------------
|  52   |  68      |  34      |
-------------------------------
|  101  |  12120   |  12119   |
-------------------------------
|  105  |  875     |  868     |
-------------------------------
|  140  |  40      |  40      |
-------------------------------
|  560  |  2985    |  3418    |
-------------------------------
```

[image: Report Grid]

I want to assign cells in the grid in the picture to a certain ID.  The Cell for tank 110 would always be the Target of ID=50 and Actual of ID=50 for example.  Many of the IDs returned aren't going to be populated in the table, just the 10 displayed in this table. Is there any way to perform a SELECT, or equivalent in the textbox as an expression to get these specific values from the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee210531.aspx) function.

This should get the ID #50 and output its Target:

```
=Lookup(50, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Target.Value, "DSStepInfo")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if it were me I'd just use a Case statement, something like

```
SELECT 
Case [ID]
    WHEN 10 Then 'Tank 50'
    WHEN 12 Then 'Tank 120'
    When 22 Then 'Tank 130'
    WHEN 50 Then 'Tank 140'
    When 52 Then 'Tank 150'
End As TankNo
,SUM([Target]) As Target
,SUM([Actual]) As Actual
FROM         tblStepComplete
WHERE        (CompleteID = @ParamID)
Group By [ID]
```

And then build your report using the values presented. Better would be an additional table that had the Tank names linked to the IDs you are pulling, but if you don't have that then the Case statement is fairly easy to maintain.